# How do I add React component on button click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to have an `Add input` button that, when clicked, will add a new `Input` component. The following is the React.js code that I thought is one way of implementing the logic that I want, but unfortunately it's doesn't work.

The exception that I got is:

> invariant.js:39 Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as
> a React child (found: object with keys {input}). If you meant to
> render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the
> object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the
> render method of `FieldMappingAddForm`.

How do I solve this problem?

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";


class Input extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <input placeholder="Your input here" />
        );
    }
}


class Form extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {inputList: []};
        this.onAddBtnClick = this.onAddBtnClick.bind(this);
    }

    onAddBtnClick(event) {
        const inputList = this.state.inputList;
        this.setState({
            inputList: inputList.concat(<Input key={inputList.length} />)
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.onAddBtnClick}>Add input</button>
                {this.state.inputList.map(function(input, index) {
                    return {input}   
                })}
            </div>
        );
    }
}


ReactDOM.render(
    <Form />,
    document.getElementById("form")
);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Remove `{}`., it is not  necessary using it in this case

```
{this.state.inputList.map(function(input, index) {
  return input;
})}
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/36715/)

or better in this case avoid `.map` and just use `{this.state.inputList}`,

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/36745/)

Answer (score 28):

**React Hook Version** 
 
[Click here for live example](https://codesandbox.io/s/infinite-component-onclick-oery4)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const Input = () => {
  return <input placeholder="Your input here" />;
};

const Form = () => {
  const [inputList, setInputList] = useState([]);

  const onAddBtnClick = event => {
    setInputList(inputList.concat(<Input key={inputList.length} />));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={onAddBtnClick}>Add input</button>
      {inputList}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Form />, document.getElementById("form"));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const [visible,setVisible] = useState(false);
return(
    <>
    <button onClick={()=>setVisible(true)}>Hit me to add new div</button>
    {
      visible ? (
        <div id='addThisContainer'>
          {/* Your code inside */}
        </div>
       ) : null
    }
  </>
)
```